# Optimizing Query in Power Query M

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to get some statistics about my DB and my code seems to work perfect, but I got a real big DB and after trying to run this script on it, I ended up alway with Timeout failure, doesn't matter if I removed some unnecessary rows or not , I still getting the same error and the script is the following :

```
let
Source = Sql.Database("DBTEST","DB_TST",[CreateNavigationProperties=false]),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source , each ([Kind] = "Table")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn( #"Filtered Rows", "Profile",
each Table.Profile([Data])),

#"Expanded Profile" = Table.ExpandTableColumn( #"Added Custom" ,
"Profile",
{"Column", "Min", "Max", "Average", "StandardDeviation", "Count", 
"NullCount", "DistinctCount"},
{"Column", "Min", "Max", "Average", "StandardDeviation", "Count", 
"NullCount", "DistinctCount"})
in
#"Expanded Profile",
#"Entfernte Spalten" = Table.RemoveColumns(Tables_profile,{"Data"}),
#"Gefilterte Zeilen" = Table.SelectRows(#"Entfernte Spalten", each true)
in
#"Gefilterte Zeilen"
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way.

```
Sql.Database("Server", "Database", "[Query=" Select * From...", CommandTimeout=#duration(0, 5, 0, 0)])
```

Comment: Adding the CommandTimeout property in the Source step is the normal way to handle this. You can also see which steps are folding the query to the server by right-clicking on the step and checking if the View Native Query menu entry is enabled.